# Why does VB Len(x) report different value than C# System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(x)?

Tags: c#, vb.net

VB:

```
Structure WAVEFORMATEX
    Dim FormatTag As Short
    Dim Channels As Short
    Dim SamplesPerSec As Integer
    Dim AvgBytesPerSec As Integer
    Dim BlockAlign As Short
    Dim BitsPerSample As Short
    Dim Size As Short
End Structure
```

C#:

```
    struct WAVEFORMATEX
    {
        public short FormatTag;
        public short Channels;
        public int SamplesPerSec;
        public int AvgBytesPerSec;
        public short BlockAlign;
        public short BitsPerSample;
        public short Size;
    }
```

VB Len() returns 18.  C# System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf() returns 20.  Any idea why?

Comment: it's because  Marshal.SizeOf()  is returning an exact 4 byte alignment size (for marshalling types to unmanaged code) . The last short in the struct is padded out to a multiple of 4 bytes for marshalling (That's assuming you are compiling to target 32 bit)

Comment: @MitchWheat well done for knowing the exact difference. Feel free to edit it into my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docs on `Strings.Len` state:

> If an `Object` contains any other type, it will return the size of the object as it will be written to the file by the `FilePut` function.

This uses a quite compacted format.

Whereas `Marshal.SizeOf` is used for size calculations for Interop, with for example `Marshal.StructureToPtr`. This can often pad out small values to 32 or 64 bits, adding to the size.

So the algorithm is different because the end purpose is different.

Comment: Can you recommend a closer equivalent in C# for what Len() is doing in VB?

Comment: No, because `FilePut` is not something that has any equivalent in C#. You can still call `Len` and `FilePut` by adding `Microsoft.VisualBasic` as a reference.